# How to get the authentication id of a user with a LOCAL session in Firebase after reloading the site?

Tags: javascript, firebase, authentication, session, firebase-authentication

Users can sign in with Firestore and the authentication data should be stored in the Browser with a LOCAL session.

```
firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL)
.then(() => {
           // Existing and future Auth states are now persisted in the current
           // session only. Closing the window would clear any existing state even
           // if a user forgets to sign out.
           // ...
           // New sign-in will be persisted with session persistence.
           return firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
               .then((userCredential) => {
                   // Signed in
                   const user = userCredential.user;
                   return user;
                   // ...
               })
               .catch((error) => {
                   const errorCode = error.code;
                   const errorMessage = error.message;
                   return errorCode;
               });
       })
.catch((error) => {
           // Handle Errors here.
           const errorCode = error.code;
       });
```

After reloading the site I want to access the LOCAL stored data, but when I use

```
const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
console.log(user)
```

The result is undefined. How can I access the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to subscribe to auth state changes:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
  }
});
```